# AppleScript Variables in Python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, applescript, speech-recognition

Why does this not work?  I am trying to set a python variable equal to applescript code.

```
from os import system
cmd = """osascript<<END
    tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    set theResponse to listen for {"good", "bad", "weather"}
    end tell
    END"""
response = str(system(cmd))
print response
if response == "good":
    print "Ok"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not work". One thing I see is that END should start from beginning of the line, not with an indent.

Comment: Try to run it and you will know what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

According to Python documentation, `os.system()` only returns an exit code; any output goes to `stdout`. Use `subprocess` instead. There's an example [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/osascript.html).

If you need to pass more complex arguments or call specific handlers, another option is to use NSAppleScript via PyObjC; there's a convenience wrapper [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-applescript).

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to get results from an AppleScript in python:

```
from Foundation import NSAppleScript

textOfMyScript = """
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    set theResponse to listen for {"good", "bad", "weather"}
end tell
"""
myScript = NSAppleScript.initWithSource_(NSAppleScript.alloc(), textOfMyScript)
results, err = myScript.executeAndReturnError_(None)

myWord = results.stringValue()
if myWord == "good":
    print ("OK")
```

If the Apple Event returns more than one thing, then you need to use:

```
myData = results.descriptorAtIndex_(2).stringValue()
```

where 2 is the index (starting at 1). You'll probably want some error handling.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after turning on dictation on system preferences and
 selecting enhanced dictation

```
from os import system
cmd = """osascript<<END
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
set theResponse to listen for {"good", "bad", "weather"}
end tell
"""
response = str(system(cmd))
   print(response)
if response == "good":
  print("Ok")
```